# Getting input from a ViewUserControl back to the controller on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'll admit I'm new to MVC and this question might be a single case of RTFM. But I'm googling this problem and I can't seem to find a solution.

I've got a simple view used to fill out some details for a specific model. I need to render part of the form using `Html.Partial` (in truth this is a wrapper which renders old non-MVC controls used from another project).

I've no problems getting data FROM the controller INTO the view.

So what's the issue? How do I get user input from the partial view back to the controller after the user pressed the submit button?

---

Here's the view and controller I've currently got:

```
@model Poll

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Poll</h4>
        <hr />
        @*@Html.ValidationSummary(true)*@
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.Partial("~/ControlPlaceholder/QuestionPlaceholder.ascx", Model, new ViewDataDictionary(Model))

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Fill" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

The view has been copied almost one-to-one from the standard generated edit view available in MVC5. Note that this is currently just a PoC - normally the whole thing should render a `QuestionPlaceholder` for every question in a `Poll`.

Here's the relevant part of the controller:

```
    //
    // GET: /Poll/Fill
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Fill(Guid id)
    {
        var poll = pollRepository.Get(id);
        return View(poll);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Poll/Fill
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Fill(Poll poll, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(poll);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to include you view and controller

Comment: So long as you partial renders inputs with name attributes that match you model property names then they will be bound to your model. But you mentioned a collection of questions. In this case using a partial will not work because it wont index your properties correctly and if you have any checkboxes in the partial, `FormCollection` wont work either. Note you don't need the 3rd parameter in @Html.Partial (you already pass the model in the second parameter)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know about the 3rd parameter - that was me messing around trying to get things to stick. If possible I'd like the `QuestionPlaceholder` to always return a string (might be a JSON in the most extreme case) - however, that string would need to be "parsed" from the underlying control, and there I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just create an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Question` and have everything bind correctly?

Comment: @StephenMuecke It probably would be easier... assuming I didn't have to share the question controls with other projects. As it is, the question controls are shared with another non-MVC project, this is why I have a placeholder which loads them and I need to rely on that somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is so simple, just set name of inputs same as corresponding action parameters and let MVC ModelBinder do it's job.  it's not important to render a partial in the form, it's input elements value would be passed to the action on submitting form. 
another way is to use Request.Form["InputName"] that is not my first recommendation.

Comment: Since I'm using a placeholder for rendering **old-school input controls**, I don't think relying on an automated `ModelBinder` is a good idea...

Comment: why you think so? try it.

Comment: Because the questions are generated using `@foreach`, and so I cannot specify IDs, as they'd get duplicated. Ideally I'd like to have every placeholder "process" it's contents separately when the user pressed submit.

Comment: Ids with the same names could be accessed in action parameters as an array of types, it may help you that use some trick like indexing and get values of each place holder inputs.

Comment: I've checked what is returned to the controller. Firstly, MVC changes the IDs and `checkChoice` becomes `1_ctl00_checkChoice`. But, what's worse, is that only the inputs from the FIRST question are sent to the controller (sort of what Stephen Muecke mentioned in the comments).

Comment: Mvc does not change ids, the sample you've sent is clientid property of server controls in the webforms. Did you check formcollection?

Comment: I ended up using the `FormCollection` data, which is basically using `Request.Form["InputName"]`.